# Entering special characters in WolframScript

Tags: windows, command-line

I have just have installed Wolfram Engine for Windows 10. However, when I want to use it in terminal, I cannot type in the square brackets `[]`. My keyboard has a German layout, where square brackets are typed with the combination of <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>, but no character appears when I use this in `wolframscript`.

Any helpful hints, other than temporarily remap the keyboard when using it?

Comment: What do you mean by "W10 pestered a RegEx5, even with admin rights - it still works, In1:2+2 gave 4, keep fingers crossed"? I have no idea how to parse that sentence. Is it relevant to the problem?

Comment: You may remap the keys using e.g. the Mathematica file "KeyEventTranslations.tr", for only remapping in MMA or a special program like e.g.: "Clavier+" that allows different key mapping for different programs.

Comment: I have the same problem (with my Slovenian keyboard layout), but I have not yet found the solution (luckily, I don't use wolframscript often). However, note that this is not a problem of Mathematica or wolframscript, but a known bug in Windows Terminal (see for example [bug report 1](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3019) or [bug report 2](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10742)).

Comment: @MarcoB: It isn't. Probably. :-) (But it probably shows that I have a crappy decade old computer.)

Comment: @Domen: I suspected as much. Still good that I asked, Daniels suggestion is worth a try. (P.S. Nice edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in a Wolfram support article [*How do I insert special characters in WolframScript using an international keyboard?*](https://support.wolfram.com/47123), you can use

```
wolframscript -rawterm
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Just tried out the trollolo set {{,}} (as described on MathSE) :-) (As expected, warning, but {{","}} is OK and {"{","}"}) too.

Answer (score 0):

Best way for Mathematica, Wolfram and TeX is to install the US and Greek keyboard layouts in windows and use an extra USB english keyboard on notebooks. For desktop computers there exist two-language business keyboards eg by Logitech.

Windows+Space keys switch fast over the layouts list.