# How to insert/type the square brackets in Wolfram Engine/script window?

Tags: scripting, free-wolfram-engine

(Win10 with spanish QWERTY keyboard, using Fn key to obtain []. Wolfram Engine/script 13.3 or previous)

I can type the square brackets (curly braces / parentheses, curly brackets) in the "System window"/"cmd", as you can see in the upper window in the attached image, BUT

I can´type the square brackets in the "Wolfram Engine/script window" that opens Wolfran Engine/Script.

How can you type square brackets in this window?.

[image]

Comment: Please see the existing question [Entering special characters in WolframScript](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286145/entering-special-characters-in-wolframscript) for some comments about this issue.